# Jmeter need to calculate ranges based on total error percentage of the Summary Report Total error

Tags: jmeter

[image of summary report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMpXs.png)

I need to create script to use this total error % then calculate something like

- If error% is between 10 and 20 % console log message
- If error% is between 21 and 40% console log message
- If error% is between 40 and 60% console log message
- If error% is majors than 61% console log message

Any suggestions ??

a lot of different none working approaches

I tried using the performance plugin in Jenkins but didn't worked well for this case

Answer (score 0):

A "script" in which language? And are you sure you really need this because [Summariser](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#summariser) already includes this functionality

If you [run JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

The `result.jtl` is a CSV file which contains test metrics like sampler label, elapsed time, whether it was successful or not, etc.

So you could process the .jtl file somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) and calculate the failed requests percentage with [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

[image]

Code as text just in case:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()

def jtl = new File('result.jtl').readLines()

def results = jtl.takeRight(jtl.size() - 1).collect { result -> result.split(',')[7] }

def failures = results.count { it == 'false' }

def failuresPercentage = (failures * 100.0f) / results.size()

println('Percentage of failures: ' + failuresPercentage + '%')
```

and in action:

[image]